# PHP ffmpeg from command line

Tags: php, ffmpeg

When i run the ffmpeg command directly in the command line it is working. But when i used the php command is breaking and getting error (At least one output file must be specified)

**Code directly in command line**

```
ffmpeg -i "F:/Sites/raaga_deploy36/mp4/arul/ghajini_rahath-96.mp4" -y -c copy  -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -flags global_header -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list "F:/Sites/raaga_deploy36/mp4/m3u8/ghajini_rahath-96.m3u8" -segment_format mpegts "F:/Sites/raaga_deploy36/mp4/m3u8/ghajini_rahath-96-segment_%05d.ts"
```

**Code from PHP**

```
$mfile=escapeshellarg($dir.$file);

$cfile=escapeshellarg($dir1.$fname.".m3u8");
$cfile_sg=escapeshellarg($dir1.$fname."-segment_%05d.ts");

$cmd="ffmpeg -i ".$mfile."-y -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -flags global_header -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list ".$cfile.".m3u8 -segment_format mpegts ".$cfile_sg;

$res=shell_exec( $cmd );
```

**Output in the command line**

```
ffmpeg -i "C:/sites/hls/mp4/arul/ghajini_orum-128.mp4
"-y -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -flags global_header -map 0 -f segment -segmen
t_time 10 -segment_list "C:/sites/hls/mp4/m3u8/ghajini_orum-128.m3u8".m3u8 -segm
ent_format mpegts "C:/sites/hls/mp4/m3u8/ghajini_orum-128-segment_ 05d.ts"
```

since the commands (line) are breaking here it is not working.

please see the link below

http://dv.raaga.com/new_ig/m3u_convert_err.jpg

Thanks

Thanigaivelan

Comment: did you try to call system? instead of shell_exec?

Comment: See if you can the entire path of the ffmpeg.exe, i mean "C:\\....\\ffmpeg. That worked for me once.